# instagram api https redirect uri

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, instagram

I've started working with Instagram's api.
As part of this usage, I allow users to authenticate with their instagram account.

My problem is the redirect uri.
In Instagram's dashboard I must specify only one value for it.
However, in my app I might need to handle two cases. 
One of them being secured (https) and the other being insecure (http).
I cannot assume that the user is always surfing on a secured enabling 
environment.

My question is, how do I enable more than one value for the redirect URI,
or how do I handle both https and http?

Answer (score 1):

[Instagram require that you always pass through https.](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

> The one thing to keep in mind is that all requests to the API must be made over SSL (https:// not http://)